# Run Concurrent queries using Snowpark Python

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement to run multiple queries in parallel asynchronously using snowpark.

I tried using collect_nowwait(), but i'm getting error as "Dataframe has no attribute named collect_nowait".

Could any one please share the detail.

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code that’s resulting in this error

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might have an old version of the API. Can you try `pip install —-force-reinstall snowflake-snowpark-python`

Comment: Sure, Thanks you